# Understanding PlotEcoPhasePlane in EcoEvo package

Tags: differential-equations, ecoevo

I'm using the `EcoEvo` package, and I'm puzzled by the behavior of `PlotEcoPhasePlane`. I have three sets of equations and want to study their equilibria and their phase-planes.

First, to install the package:

```
PacletInstall["EcoEvo", "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/cklausme/EcoEvo/master"]
```

The first system reads

```
<< EcoEvo`

SetModel[{Pop[p] -> {Equation :> -gamma   p   f}, Pop[f] -> {Equation :> gamma   p   f}, 
Pop[T] -> {Equation :> b  (1 - T) (r^n/(f^n + r^n)) (1 - 0.00262/T) - m (f^n/(f^n + r^n)) (1 - 0.00262/T)}, 
Parameters :> {gamma, b, m, r, n}}]

gamma = 0.5431799751931238`; b = 0.08850801132176628`; m = 0.9780307913586779`; r = 0.8264557187463307`; n = 14.983207992804674`

eq = SolveEcoEq[]
```

It returns two equilibria:

```
{{f -> 0, T -> 0.00262}, {f -> 0, T -> 1.}}
```

Now, if we look at its phase-plane:

```
PlotEcoPhasePlane[{f, 0, 1}, {T, 10^-10, 1}, Fixed -> {p -> 0}]
```

[image]

It doesn't seem that the plot can depict the equilibria.

The second system reads

```
<< EcoEvo`

SetModel[{Pop[p] -> {Equation :> -c  p - gamma   p   f}, Pop[f] -> {Equation :> gamma   p   f}, 
Pop[T] -> {Equation :> b  (1 - T) (r^n/(f^n + r^n)) (1 - 0.00262/T) - m (f^n/(f^n + r^n)) (1 - 0.00262/T)}, 
Parameters :> {gamma, c, b, m, r, n}}]

gamma = 0.5431799751931238`; b = 0.08850801132176628`; m = 0.9780307913586779`; r = 0.8264557187463307`; n = 14.983207992804674`; c = 0.006

eq = SolveEcoEq[]
```

It returns the same two equilibria as in the previous case:

```
{{p -> 0, f -> 0, T -> 0.00262}, {p -> 0, f -> 0, T -> 1.}}
```

And again, the phase-plane cannot show the equilibria:

```
PlotEcoPhasePlane[{f, 0, 1}, {T, 10^-10, 1}, Fixed -> {p -> 0}]
```

[image]

Now, the third system which reads

```
<< EcoEvo`

SetModel[{Pop[p] -> {Equation :> -gamma   p   f}, Pop[f] -> {Equation :> -c  f + gamma   p   f}, 
Pop[T] -> {Equation :> b  (1 - T) (r^n/(f^n + r^n)) (1 - 0.00262/T) - m (f^n/(f^n + r^n)) (1 - 0.00262/T)}, 
Parameters :> {gamma, c, b, m, r, n}}]

gamma = 0.5431799751931238`; b = 0.08850801132176628`; m = 0.9780307913586779`; r = 0.8264557187463307`; n = 14.983207992804674`; c = 0.006

eq = SolveEcoEq[]
```

and has the same equilibria as the other two:

```
{{f -> 0, T -> 0.00262}, {f -> 0, T -> 1.}}
```

its phase-plane, this time, can show the two equilibria:

```
PlotEcoPhasePlane[{f, 0, 1}, {T, 10^-10, 1}, Fixed -> {p -> 0}]
```

[image]

Is it something wrong with `PlotEcoPhasePlane`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your models are three-dimensional (with variables $p$, $f$, and $T$).  Therefore in order to plot a phase-plane diagram, you need to reduce the dimensionality to two, which the `Fixed -> {p -> 0}` does.  However in the first two systems, this causes problems because assuming $p=0$ makes $df/dt=0$ for all $f$ and $T$.  This isn't a situation that `PlotEcoPhasePlane` expects, hence the errors.

You can see better what's happening by using the `Verbose -> True` option, which prints extra debugging info, including how it numerically solves for equilibria:

```
sol=FindRoots[{True,0==-((0.978031 f^14.9832 (1-0.00262/T))/(0.0575021 +f^14.9832))+(0.0050894 (1-0.00262/T) (1-T))/(0.0575021 +f^14.9832)},Sequence[{f,0,1},{T,1/10000000000,1}]]
```

In this case, the first equation being `True` is unexpected.  Technically, all of the points on the $T$ isocline are neutrally stable equilibria.

The third case works because the extra term in $df/dt$ remains after substituting $p=0$.  You can also see that the third phase-plane diagram has two different isoclines, with equilibria where they intersect.

Thanks for pointing this out, it would be good for `PlotEcoPhasePlane` to give a warning in this degenerate case instead of inscrutable errors!

Comment: `EcoJacobian`, `EcoEigenvalues`, and `EcoStableQ` can be used, but only successfully in the second model.  In the first and third models, $dp/dt=-\gamma p f$ means that $p$ can be anything if $f=0$.  I'm not a domain expert, but they all seem a bit weird. You still have the $1/T$ terms as well. I suggest you find a modeler at your institution to discuss the model with.